# Creating a table Sql Server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

How to create SQL Server tables with 5 columns:

1 IdP column name.
2,3,4,5 column name:
a / b / c / d

**Features:**

- 1 column (int) is to have 450 rows, with IdP numbered from 1 to 450.
- The 2nd column (time) is to have a default value of 08:00:00
- 3rd column (int) default = 1
- 4th column (int) default = 0
- 5 column (int) default = NULL

**I have**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
    [IdP] [int] NULL,
    [a] [time](0) DEFAULT 08:00:00,
    [b] [int] DEFAULT 1,
    [c] [int] DEFAULT 0,
    [d] [nvarchar](5) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near object ":".

Comment: You are missing single quotes around `'08:00:00'`. This looks more of a typo to me, hence voting to close accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with supplying time value as shown below. Here is the [time (Transact-SQL) reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server.

```
[a] [time](0) DEFAULT '08:00:00'
```

Time and date values are supplied in the single quote. Also table name should be different not the reserved keyword and it is just a suggestion.

Here is the [Demo Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97911cd0f5ab75121c618803bdd24d2c).